# How to execute a Python script from another script with subprocess with full I/O?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to use this `run.py` script to run `to_run.py`. These are just some POC scripts I am using to learn. I expected full I/O, however, except only the first line from `to_run.py` (i.e, "HELLOO"), I get no output. How can I fix this?

**run.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from subprocess import PIPE,Popen
from time import sleep

p = Popen(['./to_run.py'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)

while True:
    out = p.stdout.readline().decode()
    print(out)
    print("Poll: " + str(p.poll()))
```

**to_run.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

print("HELLOO")

l1 = input("Enter first line: ")
l2 = input("Enter second line: ")

print("First line: "+l1)
print("Second line: "+l2)
```

Comment: You may need to call `sys.stdout.flush()` in the `to_run.py` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are redirecting the `stdout` output of `to_run.py` to a pipe, yet the `input` function in `to_run.py` needs to to write its prompt to `stdout` and that seems to be causing the problem. The following code demonstrates this and gets around the problem by providing the input for the `input` function by using a pipe for `stdin`. The `communicate` method is used for sending the input. I have also specified `universal_newlines=True` so that the output data are strings that do not need to be decoded.

```
import subprocess


p = subprocess.Popen(['./to_run.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate('Line 1\nLine 2\n')
print(stdout, end='')
```

**Update**

You can do it without using `communicate` by writing and reading directly to the pipes, but the docs have the following warning:

> **Warning** Use `communicate()` rather than `.stdin.write`, `.stdout.read` or `.stderr.read` to avoid deadlocks due to any of the
> other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

As far as being "interactive", my experience doing this is that you have to write all your `stdin` data up front, so it is *not* what I would consider particularly interactive. But at least you can process the output as it is produced:

```
import subprocess


p = subprocess.Popen(['./to_run.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
p.stdin.write('Line 1\n')
p.stdin.write('Line 2\n')
p.stdin.close()
for out in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''): # read rest of output
    print(out, end='')
p.stdout.close()
return_code = p.wait()
```

**Update 2**

In principal you can be completely interactive. But the problem with your particular `to_run.py` is that function `input` writes its prompt without a terminating newline and so calling `p.stdout.readline()` in `run.py` is hanging waiting for a newline character. If we modify the `to_run.py` as follows, then everything works as expected:

*to_run.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


import sys

print("HELLOO", flush=True)

print('Enter first line:', flush=True)
l1 = sys.stdin.readline()
print('Enter second line:', flush=True)
l2 = sys.stdin.readline()

print('First line:', l1, end='')
print('Second line:', l2, end='')
```

*run.py*

```
import subprocess


cmd = ['./to_run.py']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
print(p.stdout.readline(), end='') # HELLOO
print(p.stdout.readline(), end='') # Enter first line
p.stdin.write('Line 1\n')
p.stdin.flush()
print(p.stdout.readline(), end='') # Enter second line
p.stdin.write('Line 2\n')
p.stdin.flush()
p.stdin.close()
for out in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    print(out, end='')
p.stdout.close()
return_code = p.wait()
```

The following code using a separate thread to read from the `stdout` pipe seems to be what is required to handle the situation when you can't use `readline`, as is the case when the `input` function is being used. Here the thread reads characters from `stdout` one character at a time and writes to a `Queue` instance. The main thread has specialized routines that read from the queue to emulate `readline` and a special `read_prompt` that looks for the expected prompt:

```
import subprocess
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

stdout = Queue()

def rdr_thread(pipe):
    line = ''
    while True:
        buf = pipe.read(1)
        if not buf:
            stdout.put(None) # show end of file
            return
        stdout.put(buf[0])
        
def read_line():
    line = ''
    while True:
        ch = stdout.get()
        line += ch
        if ch == '\n':
            return line

def read_prompt():
    line = ''
    while True:
        ch = stdout.get()
        line += ch
        if line[-2:] == ': ':
            return line

def output_rest():
    while True:
        ch = stdout.get()
        if ch is None:
            return
        print(ch, end='')
    

cmd = ['./to_run.py']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
t = Thread(target=rdr_thread, args=(p.stdout,))
t.start()
print(read_line(), end='') # HELLOO
print(read_prompt()) # 'Enter first line: '
p.stdin.write('Line 1\n')
p.stdin.flush()
print(read_prompt()) # 'Enter second line: '
p.stdin.write('Line 2\n')
p.stdin.flush()
p.stdin.close()
output_rest()
p.stdout.close()
return_code = p.wait()
t.join()
```

**Generic Prompt Handling Using Timeout**

```
import subprocess
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue, Empty

stdout = Queue()

eof = False

def rdr_thread(pipe):
    line = ''
    while True:
        buf = pipe.read(1)
        if not buf:
            stdout.put(None) # show end of file
            eof = True
            return
        stdout.put(buf[0])
        

def read_prompt():
    """
       read until there seems to be temporarilly no more output
    """
    if eof:
        return ''
    line = ''
    try:
        while True:           
            ch = stdout.get(timeout=.5)
            if ch is None:
                break
            line += ch
    except Empty:
        pass
    return line

    

cmd = ['./to_run.py']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
t = Thread(target=rdr_thread, args=(p.stdout,))
t.start()
print(read_prompt(), end='')
p.stdin.write('Line 1\n')
p.stdin.flush()
print(read_prompt(), end='')
p.stdin.write('Line 2\n')
p.stdin.flush()
p.stdin.close()
for chunk in iter(read_prompt, ''):
    print(chunk, end='')
p.stdout.close()
return_code = p.wait()
t.join()
```

Comment: One problem though. What if there's no way to predict the path of execution of the program/script to be executed? In other words, does .communicate() end the program even if it wasn't executed fully just to give an output? How can I run a program completely interactively doesn't matter how many lines are to be input/outputted?

Comment: Alright, lemme try it. I wish there was a way.

Comment: I've added 2 more versions. The first version further demonstrates the problem and will work for those situations where `readline` can always be used . The final version is an actual solution (I believe) that requires using a separate thread for reading from the `stdout` pipe and is required for when you cannot  always use `readline` because the program you are running is waiting for input but its last output did not end with a newline.

Comment: That is a very good way to do it, handling the `stdout` in a completely different thread. One last question, is it possible to detect when a script might be throwing a prompt? I wanted to make a generic script, so that it works even if the prompt might not end with a `:`. What might be the best approach? I was thinking of extending your idea to check if more chars keep coming, and if not, then it might be a prompt. But is it good?

Comment: You either have to know the *protocol* of  the program you are dealing with as in the case we have above or perhaps modify `method get_prompt` to do `stdout.get(timeout=some_timeout_value)`, which will timeout after `some_timeout_value` seconds and throws a `queue.Empty` exception, which you must be prepared to catch. You just have to pick a good value for `some_timeout_value` from which you can deduce that there is no available output because the program is waiting for input as opposed to your retrieving the data faster than the program is able to generate it.

Comment: I've added an example of using a timeout for the general case.